# mysqli query returns no results

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to mysqli and I am trying to output a simple query into an HTML table.
I get three blank cells returned but nothing inside of them.

I tried looking around here to find this and maybe my search skills aren't up to par, so either nobody else got stuck here, or I can't search for squat!
Anyway, this is my code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "webuser", "mysecretpassword", "userdb");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ( $result = $mysqli->query("select first_name, last_name, last_activity_date from  users order by first_name" ) )
{
   $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
   foreach ( $finfo as $val )
   {
      echo "<tr>\n";
      echo "<td>$val->first_name</td>\n";
      echo "<td>$val->last_name</td>\n";
      echo "<td>$val->last_activity_date</td>\n";
      echo "</tr>\n";
   }
   $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

While I have seen other examples using printf() I am not familiar with its syntax since I am not used to C style printf since I had used the echo style previously on my old database transactions.

Any help is greatly appreciated here.  Thanks!

Comment: use `{...}` around your `$val->prop`

Comment: If you are unsure of how to print a value, you can always try var_dump($val)

Comment: Use fecth_object instead of fetch_fields http://br.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: i am not a php person... but fetch_fields maybe only returns the field descriptions, not the content?

Comment: Yes you want `fetch_all` instead of `fetch_fields` which just returns info about the columns (name, type etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
foreach ( $finfo as $val )
{
  echo "<tr>\n";
  echo "<td>" . $val->first_name . "</td>\n";
  echo "<td>" . $val->last_name . "</td>\n";
  echo "<td>" . $val->last_activity_date . "</td>\n";
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Concatenating the string made no difference I get the header and three blank rows.  I should get about 72 rows returned.  The query works from the mysql prompt.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $result = $mysqli->query("select first_name, last_name, last_activity_date from worker order by first_name" ) )
{
     while ( $val = $result->fetch_object() )
     {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $val->first_name . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $val->last_name . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $val->last_activity_date . "</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
     }
     $result->close();
}
```

Comment: This seems to had made the difference, when I used the old mysql connectors, I had always used the foreach method to output the data.  Not sure why this made any difference.  But the first method I think you are correct, the fact it returned three blank rows showed that it just returned the three columns I had selected.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the foreach or while loop, fetch_fields does not return the query result but the meta data about the columns of the query result (such as name, length, type etc)

You should also get a PHP warning as well on `$val->first_name` since this object member isn't defined.